# Class not found for ElasticsearchDSL builder

Tags: php, elasticsearch, dsl, ongr

I'm getting the error 'PHP Fatal error: Class 'Search' not found'. For the following query:

```
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Search;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\MatchQuery;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\BoolQuery;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$hosts = ['address'];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();

//$matchQueryForUser1 = new ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\MatchQuery('from', 'bob.allen');
$search = new Search();
$matchQueryForUser1 = new MatchQuery("from", "bob.allen");
$matchQueryForUser2 = new MatchQuery("env-from", "bob.allen");
$search->addQuery($matchQueryForUser1, BoolQuery::SHOULD);
$search->addQuery($matchQueryForUser2, BoolQuery::SHOULD);
$search->addParameter("minimum_number_should_match", 1);
$params = [
   'index' => 'mdeveresponsecom196912',
   'type' => 'message',
   'body' => $search->toArray(),
];

$results = $client->search($params);
print_r($results);
```

But when I run the following query it works fine, which makes me wonder is the issue with my namespaces, which from the source files it looks like has changed. Any thoughts?

```
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Search;
use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\MatchAllQuery;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$hosts = ['address'];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();

$matchAll = new MatchAllQuery();
$search = new Search();
$search->addQuery($matchAll);

$params = [
   'index' => 'mdeveresponsecom196912',
   'type' => 'message',
   'body' => $search->toArray(),
];

$results = $client->search($params);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of your script?

Comment: Yes, tried that. Besides with the match_all query it works fine and the 'require`'vendor/autoload.php';` is in the same place.

Comment: Figured it out. The namespaces have changed for most of the queries. Here's a link for anyone else it might help in the future [link](https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchDSL/releases/tag/5.0.0)